# Discontinued Sequence with pgr_ksp() result

Tags: postgis, pgrouting

I'm having some troubles with the result I got with pgr_ksp, which returns me a result with missing data.

Here is a preview of the answer, where you can see the sequence gets discontinued, and data missing:

[image]

Sequence goes from 3 to 11, and also skipping 13 and 15.

Here is the example of the query:

```
SELECT seq, path_id AS route, path_seq, node, edge,
    cost as duration,
    e.distance as distance,
    e.route as route,
    ST_AsGeoJSON(e.the_geom)::json->'coordinates' as polyline,
    agg_cost
FROM pgr_ksp('SELECT e.id AS id,
        source::integer,
        target::integer,
        duration::double precision AS cost,
        reverse_cost::double precision as reverse_cost
    FROM edges e
    GROUP BY e.id, source, target, distance, cost, reverse_cost
    ORDER BY e.id',
    2967, 17670, 6, true, false)  AS ksp
LEFT JOIN edges AS e ON e.id = ksp.edge
```

Would it be because the edge table got too many data?

Comment: Can you post the query?

Comment: And can you also try to run this once not with pgAdmin3 but using PostgreSQL command line terminal?

Comment: @FabienAncelin, just added in the post.

Comment: @dkastl , actually I have the same result when I process it on the server directly in the API I've created.

Comment: Also the I didn't have any issue with my previous DB (around 22k edges), and the issue appeared when I've updated the DB with new edges (around 28k edges).

Comment: Have you tried running pgr_ksp without running the join. Do you also miss rows without doing the left join to the edge table?

Comment: Thanks @FabienAncelin. I now got the whole sequence. 

But now I have to see on why it discontinued the result, cause I see need to join that table.

Comment: One thing that may happen is that you have 2 tables with the same name but in different schema since you are not using fully qualified names in your query. You may want to check that.

Comment: @FabienAncelin, I still haven't found the exact source of the issue previously, but you were right. Without the join table it works well. Then I've done subqueries in the SELECT part and it worked well. Thanks for the help.